# Line graph is blurry, not clear & axes positioning difficulties in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot (with ggplot2) a simple time-velocity graph in R, but my data looks messy. I am using Markdown Notebook.

I am using this base code for this:

```
 ggplot(data, aes(x = time, y = velocity)) + geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(name="Time (s)", 
    limits=c(min(data$time),max(data$time)),breaks=seq(0,3000,500)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="", limits=c(-1,max(data$velocity))) + 
    theme(axis.text = element_text(color="black"),axis.title = element_text( 
    color="black"))
```

This is how it looks like with the default settings:
[image: velocity graph with default settings]

After that, I tried to extend the figure horizontally, but then the labels became really small, and the data is still kind of blurry:
[image: horizontally extended graph]
For this, I added the following (at the beginning of my Chunk):

```
{r fig1, fig.width=95, fig.asp = 0.15}
```

If I make the font sizes bigger the labels look okay, but the velocity graph stays the same (naturally). Does someone know a way to fix that? I thought that maybe this is because of my monitor, it has 4K resolution, but I'm not sure. I also wonder if anyone knows how to move the y-axis so it would start at the zero point of the x-axes (now there's a space, and it looks weird).

I am also open to suggestions on how to improve the visualization. :D Thank you in advance!

with the changed DPI (comment) it looks better in my opinion, but the figure is really small (I included the output window for reference):
[image: DPI change]

Comment: Try changing DPI `{r fig1, fig.asp = 0.15, dpi = 600}`

Comment: Isn't `fig.width` in inches - 95 inches is huge